# GWT inject script element into the html file

Tags: gwt

On my gwt project. i have a script that call the dictionary:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=conf/iw_dictionary.js></script>
```

instead of writing this script element in the html file. i want to inject it into the html from the entry point, on the module load.

how can i do it?

Comment: A similar question was also asked: [GWT: deferred loading of external JS resources](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7968831/320399)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `com.google.gwt.core.client.ScriptInjector`, since it was created specifically for stuff like this

```java
ScriptInjector.fromUrl("conf/iw_dictionary.js").setCallback(
  new Callback<Void, Exception>() {
     public void onFailure(Exception reason) {
       Window.alert("Script load failed.");
     }
    public void onSuccess(Void result) {
      Window.alert("Script load success.");
     }
  }).inject();
```

Comment: `ScriptInjector` class is available in GWT_V2.7.0. If I have to inject a javascript file with GWT_V.1.x then Is it possible or not?

Comment: It is possible, but you'll have to use solutions from answers below. You can use answer provided by Dom (but you'll have to use older api for element creation) or Thomas Broyer answer (I'm not 100% sure if it was working for GWT 1.XX)

Comment: I'm implementing CSRF guard in my web application. I have done all the required configuration and I can see token getting generated/injected into the request header.

Let me tell you application's architecture a bit, I have JSP pages which makes call to services using Ajax to get the data and display in the UI.

My question here is "Can we protect service calls also with CSRF guard?" If it is possible then how can I do this because it is not going to CsrfGuardFilter.java class when I'm debugging the execution.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8):

Basically you inject the script element in your onModuleLoad():

```java
    Element head = Document.get().getElementsByTagName("head").getItem(0);
    ScriptElement sce = Document.get().createScriptElement();
    sce.setType("text/javascript");
    sce.setSrc("conf/iw_dictionary.js");
    head.appendChild(sce);
```

The browser will automatically load it as soon as it's injected.

Comment: Useful for those of us using 2.3 (ScriptInjector is introduced in 2.4)

Comment: I'm implementing CSRF guard in my web application. I have done all the required configuration and I can see token getting generated/injected into the request header.

Let me tell you application's architecture a bit, I have JSP pages which makes call to services using Ajax to get the data and display in the UI.

My question here is "Can we protect service calls also with CSRF guard?" If it is possible then how can I do this because it is not going to CsrfGuardFilter.java class when I'm debugging the execution.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply add a [`<script>` element in your *.gwt.xml file](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideAutomaticResourceInclusion).

```
<script src='conf/iw_dictionary.js' />
```

`onModuleLoad` will only be called once the script is loaded (as if you had it in your html page).

Comment: As I understand from you that I have to put `<script src='conf/iw_dictionary.js' />` in `Main.gwt.xml` file. My question to you is, Will this work in gwt V1.XXXX too?

Comment: Yes. It however won't work (by default at least) starting with GWT 2.7, as the default linker is now `xsiframe` which doesn't support `<script>` in module files (you then have to use `ScriptInjector` or include the script in your HTML host page instead).

Comment: I'm implementing CSRF guard in my web application. I have done all the required configuration and I can see token getting generated/injected into the request header.

Let me tell you application's architecture a bit, I have JSP pages which makes call to services using Ajax to get the data and display in the UI.

My question here is "Can we protect service calls also with CSRF guard?" If it is possible then how can I do this because it is not going to CsrfGuardFilter.java class when I'm debugging the execution.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The answers form jusio, Dom and Thomas Broyer are all valid here. In my particular case, I was looking to inject a series of polyfill scripts into GWT for some IE8 support we needed when running native JS code. The polyfill scripts needed to be available to the GWT iframe's window context - NOT the host page. To do that, using `ScriptInjector` was the correct approach as it attaches the script at that level. You can make `ScriptInjector` install the scripts to a host window by using `setWindow(TOP_WINDOW)`. Adding scripts with the `<script>` tag in my *.gwt.xml file seemed to be attaching to the host window as did using @Dom's approach.